# UISplitView as something other than the root view

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, rootview

I want to use the UISplitViewController in my app but not as the root view for my app. i want there to be several other screens before the one that uses the split view (ie login). the problem is that all the examples i can find have the UISplitViewController set as the root view for the app and i just cant seem to figure out how to make it as the controller for another screen.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options I can think of:

1) Have the pre-split view screens be on top of the split view, then when you are done with the login process, hide them.

2) When you are done with the login process, make the split view then and set it as the root view controller of the main window.  According to the [UIWindow documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html), if you set the rootViewController property on a window with an existing view hierarchy, it removes the old views and installs the new ones.